# Create a curved wall with body in COCOS2D Chipmunk IOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I am looking to have a curved wall in my game, but I'm not sure how to create a physical body to match the shape of the curved wall.

I was thinking of creating lots of smaller segments and either pivoting them together, or just fixing them in place next to each other, but wanted to know if there was an easier way to do this?

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be appreciated.

Comment: I miss that part where you added what you already tried and what error you're getting. please read How to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask And How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The question was designed to ensure that I didn't waste time coding if there was a better way to do it. I was asking advice before I started something, or are we not allowed to ask for advice?

Comment: We don't want opinionated answers.  At this point your question is to broad and will get opinionated answers